# System.StringException: Invalid id: Demo

Tags: apex, trigger, master-detail

I'm trying to insert records into a custom object called `Webinar_Attendee__c`.
In that I have a master-detail field called `Webinar__c`. When I insert records I get an error like:

> System.StringException: Invalid id: Demo

How can I insert values into a master-detail field?

Here is my apex class:

```
public class AdobeToLead {

     public static void adobeToLeads(List<Lead> leads){     
         Set<String> accNames = new Set<String>();
         List<Webinar_Attendee__c> wadd = new List<Webinar_Attendee__c>();

         List<Account> acclist =[SELECT id,Name from Account LIMIT 1];
         for(Account a : acclist){
                accNames.add(a.Name);   
         }
         for(Lead l : leads){

              if(accNames.contains(l.Company)){

                  List<Contact> clist = [Select ID From Contact Where Account.Name=:l.Company AND LastName=:l.LastName LIMIT 1];
                  System.debug('clist ::: '+clist);
                  if(clist!=null){
                  for(Contact c1 : clist){

                      Webinar_Attendee__c  wa = new Webinar_Attendee__c();
                      wa.Contact__c = c1.id;

                      l.addError('Duplicate Found');
                   }                  
                }
             }
                   else{ 

                       LightiningEd__Webinar__c lw = [select id,OwnerId,Name from LightiningEd__Webinar__c limit 1];                         
                       Webinar_Attendee__c wae = new Webinar_Attendee__c();
                       wae.Name = l.FirstName;                       
                       wae.LightiningEd__Last_Name__c = l.LastName;                     
                       wae.LightiningEd__Account_Name__c = l.LightiningEd__Account_Name__c;

                      wae.LightiningEd__Webinar__c = lw.Name ;//here i get the error (LightiningEd__Webinar__c is a master-detail field)                    

                      wadd.add(wae);


         }

             if(!wadd.isEmpty()){          
                   insert wadd;
     }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set a relationship (either Lookup or Master-Detail) by Id, not name

Instead of:

```
myRecord.LookupField__c = otherRecord.Name;
```

Use:

```
myRecord.LookupField__c = otherRecord.Id;
```